# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException' with message 'Unknown domain notify' in /twilio-php/Twilio/Rest/Client.php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Am trying to send push notifications to mobile devices using Twilio Notify with PHP, For this first creating a user using following code

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$accountSid = "sid";
$authToken = "your_auth_token";

$serviceSid = "serviceSid";

// Initialize the client
$client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);
// Create a user
$user = $client
    ->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->users->create([
        'identity' => 'push token', //am not sure what is identity also?
        'segment' => ['segmentName']
    ]);
// print_r($user);
echo $user->sid;
```

Getting an exception in

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\TwilioException' with message 'Unknown domain notify' in Twilio/Rest/Client.php
```

How to solve this? Googled a lot but no luck.

Comment: which version of twilio are you using?

Comment: Mine is: 5.11
const MAJOR = 5;
    const MINOR = 11;
    const PATCH = 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are currently using Twilio PHP 5.11.0. [Twilio Notify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/) is a beta product right now so is not included in the main library.

You will need to [install the alpha version of the library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php#accessing-preview-twilio-features) that includes beta and preview products. You can install this with composer with

```
composer require twilio/sdk:5.11.0-alpha1
```

As for the identity, that refers to the identity of a [User](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/users-resource) in Notify. To send notifications you need to create [bindings](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/bindings), which are addresses for your users to receive notifications on. Then when you create a notification you supply the identity of the user to send the notification to.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are using 5.x version from your code

so use this code to create a user

```
$notification = $client
    ->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
        'identity' => '00000001',
        'body' => 'Hello Bob'
    ]);

echo $notification->sid;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick Reply.But this is for normal push notification, not a chat. Can you please help me what is Identity also?

Comment: identity is i guess you need to create in the twilio account and add users with there phone numbers, and then pass that identity here